# how to customize Roles in eazyadmin bundle with symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, easyadmin

i am working with symfony 3 and phpMyAdmin  and i am trying to customize the menu part of the EasyAdmin bundle based on an ROLE_ADMIN or SUPPER_ADMIN_ROLE
Any HELP ??!

Comment: Please read the *How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example* (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) tutorial, your question does not follow Stack Overflow's guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box way to restrict routes to certain roles, but it is easily added. In your routes yaml you can introduce a new attribute to a route, e.g. `role`:

```
easy_admin:
    design:
        menu:
            - label: 'Products'
              icon: 'shopping-basket'
              css_class: 'label-custom-css-class'
              role: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Then you have to [overwrite](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-improved-the-overriding-of-templates#overriding-and-extending-templates) the [menu.yaml from the EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Resources/views/default/menu.html.twig). Basically you copy the code and then add a snippet that does something like:

```
{% if item.role is defined and is_granted(item.role) %}
<!-- link -->
{% endif %}
```